# Text overflow in answer body

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Some text can overflow the answer body as shown below - specifically halfway down the answer where it should read:

> appear as large as the Sun appears from the Earth (0.5°)

[image: text overflow]

If the iPhone is reoriented to landscape, nothing overflows. If again oriented to portrait, we see the overflow again. Assuming the answer isn't edited in any way, it can be found [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/16647).

- App Version: 1.5.3.5
- Device: iPhone 6s
- OS Version: Version 9.3.2 (Build 13F69)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will presumably be fixed in 1.6.  The issue became much more common in iOS 10 and the fix is described in [Questions with mathjax don't fit in the box](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283191/questions-with-mathjax-dont-fit-in-the-box/284735#284735).