# Questions with mathjax don't fit in the box

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, mathjax

This bug is intermittent, only showing up on some answers, but not others.

Sometimes, posts that have mathjax equations expand the math, but don't resize the text box, cutting off some text on the bottom.

Note that this is on the IOS public beta, so that may partially have caused the problem.

[image: Cutting off text]

- App Version: 1.5.3.5
- Device: iPhone 5s (GSM)
- OS Version: Version 10.0 (Build 14A5322e)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.6.0.4.

The problem is with how we handle height change events from the web view.

When we observe the scroll view's height changed, we get the current intrinsic content size, invalidate it, then get it again (causing a recalculation).  Only if the sizes are different do we notify the view controller that the view needs to be resized.

The problem with this approach was that we assumed we were the only ones invalidating the content size.  In iOS 10, the intrinsic content size is invalidated when it is first added to the view hierarchy (because the trait environment changes).  This makes the flow: get the current intrinsic content size (causing recalculation), invalidate it, then get it again (causing recalculation).  In this case, the content size is always the same and we never notify out.

To fix this, I'm simply recording the last notified content size and notifying if the current size is different from the last recorded size.